# Knockout JS: How should "with" or clearnNode be used to deal with Multiplle bindings error with knockout js?

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, knockout.js, bootstrap-modal

I am working on this project prototype. The current part now is dealing with "Multiple binding" issue with knockout js. I've read up on different methodologies that include using "with" statements when referencing the data model in the HTML. I've also read that using clearNode could be another possible solution when dealing with various data models to render. Here are some facts about my current problem.

- I'm using two different data model, each is created using two different JSON responses/file (local and api)
- The first modal to use and render knockout bindings is "questionDisplay"
- I capture the inputs to be included in a form submission using google docs (irrelevant but explain some of the cals in code)
- During submission of form, info gets sent to a google drive file and a "next" button is to trigger the "resultDisplay" modal
- Issue comes along at this point, I get the "Multiple bindings"

I've tried using "with" statements to "pin-point" the exact model per knock out the template, but I'm thinking because they only get instantiated during a function call it won't be accessible? I don't know how I would start to refactor code to be able to use "with" statement.

I have also tried clearNode, by including an id name to the root where the knockout declares the name for the data model, the use that id in a clearNode during the second KO render... the idea was that it would clear it then reuse the same node. Though in the code snippet I provide, I use "template" in the clear node, that because I tried every node and so happened that was the last one I tried lol

I have also read that during '.applyBindings', I can include the element name to include it too? I've tried a couple things with no success.

### PS: I should state again, this is prototype code, ergo, super messy. Shout out to Nathan Fisher (https://stackoverflow.com/users/29467/nathan-fisher)!

**JS**

```
//functions.js
function resultDisplay() {
  parseJsonWithSelect();
  var self = this;
  self.data = ko.observableArray(jresponse);
}

function questionDisplay() {
  var self = this;
  var mappedData = qna.map(function(item) {
    item.optionGroupName = "optionGroup_" + item.questionId;
    item.selectedAnswer = ko.observable();
    return item;
  });
  self.data = ko.observableArray(mappedData);
}

function initResultDisplay() {
  var dataModel = new resultDisplay();
  ko.cleanNode("template");
  ko.applyBindings(dataModel);
  $("#searchResultDisplay").modal("show");
}

function initQuestionDisplay() {
  $("#inBetween").modal("hide");
  var qnaDataModel = new questionDisplay();
  $("#questionsDisplay").modal("show");
  ko.applyBindings(qnaDataModel);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Questions modal -->
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="questionsDisplay"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="questionsDisplayLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="questionsDisplayLabel">
          QUESTIONS
        </h5>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="close"
          data-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div
        class="modal-body"
        data-bind="template: {name: 'template', data: $data}"
      ></div>
      <script type="text/html" id="template">
        <div class="diplay-frame" data-bind="foreach: {data: data, as: '_data'}">
          <div class="question-box">
              <h2 class="question" id="ques" data-bind="text: _data['question']"/>
              <div data-bind="foreach: {data: _data['answers'], as: 'answer'}">
                  <input type="radio" id="ans" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedAnswer, attr:{name: $parent.optionGroupName, value: $data}" />
                  <span data-bind="text: answer"/>
              </div>


          </div>
        </div>
      </script>
         <button
            type="button"
            onclick="captureAnswers()"
            class="btn btn-secondary"
            data-dismiss="modal"
          >
            Next
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- Search result Display Modal -->
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="searchResultDisplay"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="searchResultDisplayLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="searchResultDisplayLabel">
          Search Results
        </h5>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="close"
          data-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div
        class="modal-body"
        data-bind="template: {name: 'template', data: $data}"
      ></div>
      <script type="text/html" id="template">
        <div class="diplay-frame" data-bind="foreach: {data: data, as: '_data'}">
          <div class="result-box">
              <div class="bgtint"></div>
              <section class="businesscard">
                  <div class="flip">
                      <div class="front">
                          <div class="logo">
                              <img class="profile_image" width="50px" height="50px" data-bind="attr:{src: _data['profile_image']}"/>
                              <h2 class="user_name" data-bind="text: _data['username']"/>
                              <div class="introduction">COMPANY NAME GOES HERE!</div>
                              <div class="arrow"></div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="userinfo">
                          <ion-icon name="call">PHONE</ion-icon>
                          <div class="name">
                          </div>

                  </div>
              </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </script>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you cannot call `applyBindings` twice on the entire document and expect to get away with it ;-) But this method can indeed take an element as its second argument, so the bindings are only applied to that. So in your case, you would call:

```
ko.applyBindings(dataModel, document.querySelector('#searchResultDisplay'));
```

And:

```
ko.applyBindings(qnaDataModel, document.querySelector('#questionsDisplay'));
```

Comment: Thanks, now looking back, I had tried adding the elements as an argument using "document.getElementById" a using $ notation for the traversing. Maybe that was the problem? in any case. I made the changes, elements are binding separately. My issue now is that on the second modal window, "searchResultDisplay", is not rendering the content. I will be creating a new question and link to you here, instead of updating the question as the issue is not in scope with the question.